# I have two items that appear to be centered in the code and individually on the page, but when aligned they are not

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a button near the bottom of the page that is centered. Additionally, I have three images that I centered by making each image a col-lg-2 with 3 empty columns in between each one. I cannot figure out why these two items don't line up nicely, and which one is the one that is off center.

https://codepen.io/colesam/full/OgamyB/

[image]
SCSS:

```
a {
    color: $blue;
    font-size: 1.4vw;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.7vw;
    transition: all 0.2s;

    &:hover {
        color: $orange;
        font-size: 1.7vw;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    &:focus {
        color: $blue;
        text-decoration: none;

        &:hover {
            color: $orange;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}

body {
    background: white;
    color: $black;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-shadow: $text-shadow-light;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 5vh;
    margin-top: 5vh;
}

p {
    font-size: 3vh;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.btn-next {
    bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5vh;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.3s;

    a {
        font-size: 5vw;

        &:hover {
            font-size: 5.5vw;
        }
    }
}

.center-text {
    text-align: center;
}

.left-text {
    text-align: left;
}

.no-margin {
    margin: 0;
}

.right-text {
    text-align: right;
}

.title {
    padding-left: 4vw;

    h3 {
        font-size: 3vw;
        text-shadow: $text-shadow;
    }
}

#portfolio-page {
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 2vw;
}

.active-item {
    box-shadow: $box-shadow-o;
        -moz-box-shadow: $box-shadow-o;
        -webkit-box-shadow: $box-shadow-o;
}

.btn-portfolio {
    padding-top: 20vh;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.3s;

    a {
        font-size: 5vw;

        &:hover {
            font-size: 5.5vw;
        }
    }
}

#featured-content {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 65vh;
    margin-top: 2vh;
    padding: 3vh 0;
}

#featured-img img {
    box-shadow: $box-shadow-light;
        -moz-box-shadow: $box-shadow-light;
        -webkit-box-shadow: $box-shadow-light;
}

#primary-featured {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 45.5vh;
    top: 10%;
}

#secondary-featured {
    margin-top: 3vh;
}
```

HTML(inside a div.container):

```
<div id="portfolio-page">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <h2 class="center-text">My Portfolio</h2>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" id="featured-content">
            <div class="row no-margin">
                <div class="col-lg-1 btn-portfolio" id="left-button">
                    <a><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-1" id="primary-featured">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-5" id="featured-img">
                            <img src="includes/img/headers.jpg" alt="A cluster of header images." class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1" class="center-text">
                            <h4 id="featured-title">Placeholder</h4>
                            <hr>
                            <p id="featured-description">Placeholder text.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-1 btn-portfolio" id="right-button">
                    <a><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3" id="secondary-featured">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-2" id="secondary-feature1">
                            <img src="includes/img/placeholder.jpg" alt="A placeholder image." class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-3" id="secondary-feature2">
                            <img src="includes/img/placeholder.jpg" alt="A placeholder image." class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-3" id="secondary-feature3">
                            <img src="includes/img/placeholder.jpg" alt="A placeholder image." class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 btn-next">
            <a>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Your problem is with position: absolute on .btn-next.

> For absolutely positioned elements
>
> This property specifies the distance between the left margin edge of
> the element and the left edge of its containing block.

You have margin-left: -15px, so it aligns to center with the margin-left: -15px.

**How to fix:**

Add this to .btn-next:

```
right: 0;
left: 0;
```

...or you can remove position: absolute from .btn-next.

**Alternative option:**

The "down arrow" at the bottom isn't centered, because it's in the row class and that class has margin-left: 15px and margin-right: 15px.

If you give it margin: 0px, it'll be fine.

Rename div class="row" to something else or give it another class like div class="row down".

Examples:

```
<div class="down">
    <div class="col-lg-12 btn-next">
        <a>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="row down">
    <div class="col-lg-12 btn-next">
        <a>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (only if using second option):

```
.row.down {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it worked! Thank you. I don't understand why removing 15px from the left and right margin would help center it. Removing 15px from the left would shift it left, and vice versa, but removing both should just increase the width of the element, no?

Comment: I also can't seem to center the icon within the anchor tag. My btn-next class has the text-align: center; property but it won't center the icon.

Comment: I have a different and better solution, I edit my answer in a minute.